# How to iterate array using recursive function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, iteration

I have array:

`x = ['A', 'AA', 'AAA'];`

How can I iterate it so output is:

```
car_A
car_A_AA
car_A_AA_AAA
```

```
x.forEach(value => {
 ???
});
```

How can I do this simplest way? Do I have to call method recursively?

Any help would really appreciated

Comment: Or for the complete output: `x.map((_, i, arr) => "car_" + arr.slice(0, i + 1).join("_"));`.

Comment: @SebastianSimon I get the following out put: `["car_A,AA,AAA"]`

Real output: `["car_A, car_A_AA, car_A_AA_AAA"]`

Comment: @TanvirAlam [No, you don’t](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkwNQ.png).

Answer (score 2):

How about a classic for loop with join:

```js
const x = ["A", "AA", "AAA"]
const prefix = "car_"
for (let i = 1; i <= x.length; i++) {
  console.log(prefix + x.slice(0, i).join("_"))
}
```

**Relevant MDN Documentation:**

- [Array.prototype.**slice()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)
- [Array.prototype.**join()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

***Edit:*** if you require the output in the form of an array:

```js
const x = ["A", "AA", "AAA"]
const prefix = "car_"
const output = []
for (let i = 1; i <= x.length; i++) {
  output.push(prefix + x.slice(0, i).join("_"))
}
console.log(output)
```

Comment: I get the following out put: `["car_A,AA,AAA"]` Real output: `["car_A, car_A_AA, car_A_AA_AAA"]`

Comment: @TanvirAlam See the additional code.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a recursive function if you'd like.

```js
function print(pre, sep, arr, i) {
 if (i >= arr.length) return;

 const s = pre + sep + arr[i];
 console.log(s);
 print(s, sep, arr, i+1);
}

const x = ['A', 'AA', 'AAA'];

print("car", "_", x, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think @Sebastian-Simon response is the best one so far. You can do it in a *map* function with *slice* and *join* or inside a *reduce* but being aware you're doing a side effect with that array push.

```js
const x = ['A', 'AA', 'AAA'];

const result = x.map((_, i, arr) => "car_" + arr.slice(0, i + 1).join("_"));

const result2 = [];
x.reduce((acc, val, i, arr) => {
  acc += '_' + val;
  result2.push('car' + acc);
  return acc;
}, '');

console.log(result);
console.log(result2);
```

*Reduce* option is better in performance.

Answer (score -1):

The reduce() method executes a reducer function (that you provide) on each element of the array, resulting in a single output value.

[Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```
    function handle_format (pre, connect, list){
         let result = []; 
         let tmp = []
         list.forEach(function(item){
             tmp.push(item)
             result.push( pre + connect + tmp.reduce(function(item, res){ return res = item + connect + res  }) )
         });
         return result;
    }

    handle_format (prefix, '_', list)
    // return ["car_A", "car_A_AA", "car_A_AA_AAA"]
```

Comment: I try to fix my answer. Make the answer more valued.

Comment: Sorry, I found the real problem and have fixed it. Thanks for your advice.